# Updating a Sharepoint Calendar from a VB.NET WinForm app

Tags: .net, sharepoint, calendar

I am about to endeavor in the area of the posting subject and am looking for early advice.

Is there a Sharepoint SDK that I need to install to be able to do this or shall I scan the .NET Framework for the appropriate objects to use?

Advice or useful links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to peek and poke around in the Sharepoint web services.   There are numerous web service calls exposed by Sharepoint that are a little complicated, but might be the most expedient solution.

These links will probably help you get started
http://spservices.codeplex.com/
http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/05/18/determine-the-url-of-sharepoint-web-services-using-jquery-javascript.aspx
http://www.csharphelp.com/archives4/archive602.html